# How to multiple two columns in a row with max date in PowerBi?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

This is my first PowerBi report.

I've a table structure like this

```
TransDate   UnitsAsOf   Price   InvestedAmount  Stock
01/02/2020  10          12.4    124              APL
01/03/2020  20          13      260              APL
01/05/2020  21          15      315              APL
01/10/2020  1           111     111              BPL
```

And this is the table Visualization I'm creating

```
Stock   Total invested (Summarized column)  Current Value
APL     699                                 THIS IS A MEASURE column
BPL     111
```

I just couldn't figure out how to get max(transDate) for each stock and multiple it with the Price of that row?

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
measure =
SUMX(TOPN(1, YourTable, YourTable[TransDate], DESC), YourTable[Price] * YourTable[InvestedAmount])
```

the `TOPN` will return you the row with the latest date, and in the `SUMX` you use the fields from that row.

Answer (score 0):

**OPTION-1**

You can simply create this following measure-

```
max_date = MAX(your_table_name[TransDate])
```

Now add a table visual with column - **Stock**, **InvestedAmount** (Default SUM applied) and New Measure **max_date**. The output will be as below-

[image]

**OPTION-2**

You can also add all 3 column - **Stock**, **InvestedAmount** and **TransDate** directly and select **Latest** for TransDate as shown below and **the output will be same**-

[image]